# R Is it possible to change language settings for everything apart from messages?

Tags: locale, environment

I'm running the R console of Rversion 4.2.3 (2023-03-15) -- "Shortstop Beagle" on Mac Catalina (10.15.7).
When I start R it says "Natural language support but running in an English locale" - that's brilliant - so now I want to discover what is the "Natural language" that it's talking about ? If I run Sys.getenv() I find LANG en_US.UTF-8 but, as far as I know, this only refers to the language of the messages/warnings/errors - not to everything else (?) With Sys.getlocale() it says "en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8" - perhaps this refers to the fact that settings are US English - but that it can cope with all other letters found in UTF-8 ?? (who knows ??!!).
My keyboard language was set to Polish Pro so, as everything else on the Mac is set to English - perhaps the R installation took the "Natural language" from the keyboard language ?? I don't think there is a way of checking which "Natural language" it's talking about (?) but at the moment the R console accepts Polish characters even as R objects - so that's good. Ideally I would like to set all settings to Polish EXCEPT the messages/warnings/errors (which I would like in English) - I might have this already (but as far as I know there's no way to tell in R) - if I don't have this then otherwise it seems that this is impossible - setting Sys.setenv("LANG" or "LANGUAGE" = "PL") will, as far as I know, only change the language of messages/warnings/errors. Sys.setlocale(....) might do something - but what do I put in the brackets ? (and will Sys.setenv("LANG" or "LANGUAGE" = "EN") override this ?)
And what happens if I want a new language e.g. French - does this mean I have to re-install R first making sure that the keyboard language is French ??? - or can I keep the same installation and just change the keyboard language (and if I then say Sys.setenv("LANG" or "LANGUAGE" = "EN") will this change all settings to English or only the messages/warnings/errors ?
Many thanks for your time and patience.

I've tried searching for ways to understand what "Natural language support but running in an English locale" actually means - but failed.

Comment: I have the exact same wondering. Also what language would be "unnatural"?